# Remove validation error upon change on the input field

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm new to using Vue and wondering how I can get a validation error removed from its associated input field as the input field value changes. I store my input field values in an object called `fields` inside `data()` as below (small snippet):

```
 fields: {
  email_type: '',
  date_of_birth: '',
  country_of_birth: '',
}
```

I also store my validation errors inside an object called `errors`.

When the user submits the form and gets validation errors, the error object fills up. An example is below:

```
{"email_type":["The email type field is required."],
"date_of_birth":["The date of birth field is required."],
"country_of_birth":["The country of birth field is required."]
```

To display the validation error under the input, I do:

`<small class="font-weight-bold help text-danger" v-if="errors.{{$name}}" v-text="errors.{{$name}}[0]"></small>`

A sample of my inputs are (I use Laravel blade to insert the "name" of the field) with `{{$name}}`:

`<input @change="removeValidationError(errors.{{$name}})" v-model="fields.{{$name}}" class="form-control" value="">`

The `removeValidationError()` method is what should be removing that specific validation error from the `errors` object however this is not working. My `removeValidationError` method is below:

```
removeValidationError : function(errorField){

    if(errorField !== undefined){
        console.log(errorField);
        errorField = "";
        delete errorField;
    }

},
```

As you can see I have tried both to empty the field as well as delete it but this has no effect. I do not even get any error messages in the console however when I console.log `errorField` it does display the error message.

(Additional info, I get my validation using Laravel)

What is the best approach for this? Thanks

Comment: Realistically you should validate on the frontend and the backend. I recommend a package such as Parsley.js . With that, you do not need to worry about removing laravel's validation because it should be already valid before reaching there. Then the laravel validation is more of a backup for in case somebody trys to modify the DOM or if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with your data binding done in the template, the values of an `Object`can't be evaluated using `errors.{{$name}}` in the template. It won't compile and ideally should throw an error. The correct solution is to access properties using angle brackets - `errors[$index]`

Instead of

```
<small class="font-weight-bold help text-danger" v-if="errors.{{$name}}" v-text="errors.{{$name}}[0]"></small>

<input @change="removeValidationError(errors.{{$name}})" v-model="fields.{{$name}}" class="form-control" value="">
```

It should be

```
<small class="font-weight-bold help text-danger" v-if="errors[$name]" v-text="errors[$name][0]"></small>

<input @change="removeValidationError(errors[$name])" v-model="fields[$name]" class="form-control" value="">
```

Comment: sorry I should've mentioned that I use Laravel blade to insert the name of the fields to the DOM as the inputs are a laravel component (which makes it easier for me to manage the inputs) so `errors.{{$name}}` does work fine and it would output for example as `errors.email_type`